# Probability of detection and false alarm ratio are wrong in a simple example, don't know why

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand how POD (Probability of Detection) and FAR (False Alarm Ratio) are calculated in [this paper](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~amy/pubs/mcgovern_dmkd2011.pdf).

On page 234 they are defined as usually and the tree data structure in page 239 shows POD and FAR values for a simple example but I can't figure out how they came up with those values.
$$
POD = \frac{TP}{(TP+FN)}  \\
FAR = \frac{FP}{(TP+FP)} 
$$For this example, let:

- TP = There's tornado (+ label in the series) and there's the word in the series
- FP = There's no tornado and there's the word in the series
- TN = There's no tornado and the word is not in the series
- FN = There's tornado and there's not word in the series

Then for the first word (aa), I understand that:
TP = 2; FN=0; FP=2; so POD=1 and FAR= 0.5 which is what is in the paper,

But for the second word (ab):
TP= 2; FN=0; FP=1; so POD=1, which is in the paper, but shouldn't FAR= 0.333, instead of 1/4 in the paper?

And for the third word (ac):
TP= 1; FN=1; FP=1; so POD=1/2, which is in the paper, but shouldn't FAR= 1/2, instead of 1/4 in the paper?

I don't understand what's wrong with my FAR, and if my POD are OK, as they seem to be.

Comment: Doesn't your second displayed equation have a typo (should be TN instead of TP in the denominator)?

Comment: Dilip I've been checking and I think there's no typo because in the paper in the confusion matrix in page 236 the FAR denominator is the total number of events predicted to occur so it is the first row of the confusion matrix
Karl

Comment: FAR is the ratio of false positives to the total number of occasions when the null hypothesis is true (N).  The latter is the sum TN + FP, not TP + FP as you have written. Consider that TN is number of cases when N is true and the decision (correct decision!) is that the null is true (or not rejected) while FP is the number of cases when the null is true but is incorrectly declared to be positive (false positive!). You never mention TN  at all in the data and it is not in your displayed equations. So where is TN used, and why does it need to be defined since it is not needed at all?

Comment: Thanks Dilip, the terminology in weather forecasting is confusing: in this paper they clarify it http://www.atm.helsinki.fi/~dschultz/pubs/61a-Barnesetal09-FAR.pdf what you are defining is FARate and not FARatio, FARatio is correctly defined as it is in my equation, but in the paper of my original question neither FARate nor FARatio seem to be used to get the results of page 239

Answer (score 1):

The formulas assume that the POD and FAR are probabilities but this is not necessarily true. Check whether the two "probabilities" satisfy the unit measure axiom of probability theory before assuming that they are. Otherwise you are a prime candidate for being swindled out of information.